# JavaFX WebView how to display images near JAR file

Tags: html, javafx

I have a JavaFX application in a JAR file. It contains a static `.html` file which I am trying to display in a WebView.
Everything works properly except the `<img>` tags. The images are near the JAR file and **not** inside it.

I tried to give absolute path like `D:/Tools/MyTool/image.png` and like `file://D:/Tools/MyTool/image.png`.
I figured out the path from the path of the jar file. The path is okay and the file is there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    Some Text
    <img src="D:/Tools/MyTool/image.png">
</body>
</html>
```

The `Some Text` appears properly but not the image. Do you have any idea how to display images outside the JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path to local file should follow the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) like:

```
<img src="file:///D:/Tools/MyTool/image.png">
```

Why do you need until 3 slashes? The scheme provides `file://<host>/<path>` syntax. If we omit host, it is `localhost` by default. The path above is equals to:

```
<img src="file://localhost/D:/Tools/MyTool/image.png">
```